# Symfony ReCaptcha multi translations

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, recaptcha, symfony-forms

I use symfony 1.4.11 with doctrine. And I use ReCaptcha from sfFormExtraPlugin. I have 3 language in my site. Russian, Ukrainian and English. In form I get current culture:
For example:

```
$this->widgetSchema['captcha'] = new sfWidgetFormReCaptcha(array(
                 'public_key' => sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_public_key'),
                 'theme'=>sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_theme'),
                 'culture'=>$this->options['culture'],
            ));
```

With English and Russian it is all ok. But ReCaptcha do not support Ukrainian. So when I make **[custom_translations](http://code.google.com/intl/en-GB/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html#i18n)** I have one language in all cultures. Is it possible to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using some sort of switch / select syntax and use whichever translation that matches the culture?

Skeleton code:

```
switch (culture)
  case "ukrainian":
    recaptcha.customTranslations = ukranianTranslations
  case "russian":
    recaptcha.customTranslations = russianTranslations
```

Something like that. You don't have to put all the translations on the same page since I assume that you will only show one language at a time?